# Waveform signal on wirewound resistor VS metal film resistor causes different result? Strange result!

Tags: pcb, resistors, analog

Hi to all the experts out there, please clearly understand all 5 situations mentioned below.
Take note that wirewound and metal film resistors were used.

At 'situation 4', I thought it was the PCB problem. But when I used metal film together with the PCB in 'situation 5', it worked!

If wirewound resistor is not suitable for analog / switching signal, then why am I not having problem during 'situation 2'?

So, does anyone have any idea or experience on this problem?

Is it PCB can never be used together with wirewound solder lug resistor? If yes, why?

**EDIT:** Current for situations that are 'OK!' is ~0.9A. Whereas for 'situation 4' which is 'NOT OK!', the current was ~0.4A. Leakage in the PCB? I don't think so. But if yes, why 'situation 5' has no leakage?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Correction: Not 'PCB board', should be 'PCB'. Thanks to JRE.

Comment: If the wire-wound resistor was the problem, why did it work in situation 2? I suspect you had a bad connection somewhere. Can you reproduce the problem? If so, can you post a picture of the setup and interconnects?

Comment: @marcelm Thanks for your reply. Yes I suspected that it had bad connection or bad wire. I did change different wire (tried both lower and higher AWG wires) and re-solder the connection, but no luck, it's the same. I am sorry that I couldn't post a picture because it's research lab project - P&C. I am suspecting PCB + wirewound is not ok, but why? it makes no sense..

Comment: It is not clear how the low side of the load is connected back to the signal generator 0V point, if at all, since your PCB only has one trace. You can't just connect it to the scope GND clip otherwise you are assuming a good connection via mains earth back to the signal source 0V.